# Error Assigning Delegate Using ? : Syntax

Tags: c#, delegates, method-group

I've created a delegate and two matching methods.

```
private delegate bool CharComparer(char a, char b);

// Case-sensitive char comparer
private static bool CharCompare(char a, char b)
{
    return (a == b);
}

// Case-insensitive char comparer
private static bool CharCompareIgnoreCase(char a, char b)
{
    return (Char.ToLower(a) == Char.ToLower(b));
}
```

When I try to assign either of these methods to a delegate using the following syntax (note that this code is in a static method of the same class):

```
CharComparer isEqual = (ignoreCase) ? CharCompareIgnoreCase : CharCompare;
```

I get the error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group'

I can use a regular `if ... else` statement to do this assignment and it works just fine. But I don't understand why I can't use the more compact version and I don't understand the error message. Does anyone know the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types in the conditional operator is resolved before the assignment, so the compiler can't use the type in the assignment to resolve the conditional operator.

Just cast one of the operands to `CharComparer` so that the compiler know to use that type:

```
CharComparer isEqual = ignoreCase ? (CharComparer)CharCompareIgnoreCase : CharCompare;
```

Comment: Well, that certainly fixes it. But I still don't see what the type of the conditional operator has to do with the type of the assignment.

Comment: @Jonathan: The compiler needs to resolve the type of the `x ? y : z` expression *first*, before it can look at the assignment. In your example it can’t do this.

Comment: I think the issue is that `CharCompareIgnoreCase` is of type `CharCompareIgnoreCase`, not `CharComparer`. It casts to `CharComparer`, but isn't actually that type. So, the compiler sees that, and tries to cast `CharCompare` to `CharCompareIgnoreCase`, which obviously fails. By forcing the Cast to `CharCompare`, the compiler goes "Oh, okay." and accepts the type as `CharCompare`.

Comment: I guess it's because `CharCompareIgnoreCase` is not automatically of type `CharComparer`. It only becomes that type when I assign it to a delegate of that type, or type cast it.

Comment: @Mike: Right, I wrote the comment above before seeing yours. Yes, that seems to be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly right. As long as someone has learned something, it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
CharComparer isEqual = (ignoreCase) ? new CharComparer(CharCompareIgnoreCase) : new CharComparer(CharCompare);
```